# Override/move values from bottom rows to upper rows in specific columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, overriding, move

I'm having a dataframe as shown below, and would like to move the values from 'phone', 'spotify' and 'rent' from bottom half and override the top half (essentially splitting the dataframe in two and placing the 'expense' values to the 'income'-half.

Currently, there are january thorugh december twice. I want it to just be 12 rows with values in each cell (ie no cell having 0.0 as value).

```py
                    loan      csn  salary  phone  spotify    rent
january   income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
february  income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
march     income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
april     income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
may       income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
june      income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
july      income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
august    income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
september income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
october   income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
november  income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
december  income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0    0.0      0.0     0.0
january   expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
february  expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0    149.0  3500.0
march     expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
april     expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
may       expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
june      expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
july      expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
august    expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
september expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
october   expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
november  expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
december  expense     0.0      0.0     0.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
```

**Getting data from .JSON:**

```py
        df_all = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): data[i][j] 
                           for i in data.keys() 
                           for j in data[i].keys()},
                       orient='index')
```

**.JSON file structure:**

```
{
    "january": {
        "income": {
            "loan": 1200,
            "csn": 13000,
            "salary": 2000
        },
        "expense": {
            "phone": 300,
            "spotify": 49,
            "rent": 3500
        }
        ...
```

**Desired output:**

```py
                    loan      csn  salary  phone  spotify    rent
january   income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
february  income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
march     income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
april     income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
may       income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
june      income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
july      income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
august    income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
september income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
october   income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
november  income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
december  income   1200.0  13000.0  2000.0  300.0     49.0  3500.0
```

Comment: Can you please provide the dataframe?

Comment: @XXavier I added both the way I got the dataframe and the df itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
df = df.rename(index={'expense':'income'}, level=1).fillna(0).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
df
```

Output:

```
            loan    csn  Salary  phone  spotify  rent
Apr income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Aug income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Dec income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Feb income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Jan income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Jul income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Jun income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Mar income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
May income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Nov income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Oct income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
Sep income  1200  13000  2000.0    300       49  3500
```

***Details:***

Rename index level 1 such that 'expense' becomes 'income', then use `groupby` both levels of the index.  We could use `first` but I don't think that future proof and safe, therefore, I choose to `fillna` with zero and `sum`.

Comment: I tried adding your python code but nothing happened. I didn't quite understand your details section. Sorry I'm quite new to pandas.

Comment: You need to add `df=` in front to reasssign the results to your dataframe.

Comment: You dont, by any chance, know how to remove the income-column (that has no name?) and order the table again from january through december? I cant seem to understand how to remove the income-column when it hasnt got any name (through df.drop(df.column("name")) functionality.

Comment: The month and income/expenses "columns" are really dataframe indexes.  df=df.reset_index() will mive those index levels into colums on a dataframe.

Comment: Ordering the table by calendar month is a bit more coding.  You will need to add a help column indicating the integer month or use categorical data type with ordered set to True.